# Redshift: splitting a time duration row by 24 hour period

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm also trying to split a row by 24 hours period ranges between `FromDate`, `Todate`.

For example, if a time row has given as below, (Range between `FromDate`, `Todate` is 4 days, so I want 4 rows)

```
ID---FromDate---Todate     
1---2014-04-01 08:00:00.000---2014-04-04 12:00:00.000
```

The result I want to see would be like this:

```
ID---FromDate---Todate---DateDiff(HH)
1---2014-04-01 08:00:00.000---2014-04-01 23:59:59.000---15
1---2014-04-02 00:00:00.000---2014-04-02 23:59:59.000---23
1---2014-04-03 00:00:00.000---2014-04-03 23:59:59.000---23
1---2014-04-04 00:00:00.000---2014-04-04 12:00:00.000---12
```

I have found a solution to this, but it just does not work using Redshift when I iterate inside my own auxiliary table (different from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435556/sql-server-split-a-time-duration-row-by-24-hour-period) using SQL Server!)

I am not sure if this could be possible using Redshift or if I should look for another way to solve it (like a custom function or something like that).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift has one painful "feature".  It is a pain to generate a derived table.  Let me assume that you have a table big enough to generate a tally or numbers table.

Then, the rest is date arithmetic . . . but a bit complicated.  I don't have Redshift on hand -- and it has a weird combination of date syntax from SQL Server and Postgres

```
with numbers as (
      select row_number() over () - 1 as n
      from t
     )
select t.id,
       greatest(date_trunc('day', t.fromdate) + n.n * interval '1 day', t.fromdate)  as fromdate,
       least(date_trunc('day', t.fromdate) + (n.n + 1) * interval '1 day', t.todate) as todate
       datediff(hour,
                greatest(date_trunc('day', t.fromdate) + n.n * interval '1 day', t.fromdate),
                least(date_trunc('day', t.fromdate) + (n.n + 1) * interval '1 day', todate)
               ) as hours
from t join
     numbers n
     on todate > date_trunc('day', t.fromdate) + n.n * interval '1 day';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4edaf8a26c15ff259dc81356db406707) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres that illustrates the main ideas behind this.